# Jenkins job to execute python script on remote machine

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

Want to execute python script on remote machine, for that I want to create jenkins job which will take in input the "ip" of the remote machine and run the script on that machine.

Answer (score 0):

Just basically create a script and put in wherever directory that your OS will execute the command from. For linux, ther default path might be `/usr/bin`.

For execute the script,

```
    def remoteserverip = "x.x.x.x"
    def remotessh = "user@${remoteserverip}"

stage('Example'){
    sh "ssh ${remotessh} <your script>"
}
```

make sure you already allow Jenkins to access to the remote server by setting ssh-keygen.

Comment: what if I am accessing the remote machine for the first time @bth-s3

Comment: Like I said, you have to use the ssh-keygen and copy id_rsa.pub and put into the remote directory. This article https://www.ssh.com/ssh/keygen/ could help you.

Answer (score 0):

Since I think that using credetials offers more flexibility, I want to add another options.

If you want to use ssh with a **username and password** [Jenkins's credetials](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/using/using-credentials/) are the way to go:

```
node {
  withCredentials([[
    $class: 'UsernamePasswordMultiBinding',  credentialsId: '<credential_id>',
        usernameVariable: 'USERNAME', passwordVariable: 'PASSWORD']]) {
        sh 'sshpass -p "${PASSWORD}" ssh ${USERNAME}@<host> <command>'
    }
```

You can also store **private (and encrypted) ssh-key** in Jenkins:

````
node {
    withCredentials([
      sshUserPrivateKey(credentialsId: '<credential_id>', 
      keyFileVariable: 'your_keyfile',
      passphraseVariable: '', 
      usernameVariable: 'USERNAME')]) {
        sh 'ssh -i ${your_keyfile} ${USERNAME}@<host> <command>'
    }
}
```
````